# Two resizeable divs , changing one changes the other

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to handle two resizeable divs where when I change one, the other div adjusts its size along the grid and vice versa.

I'm able achieve only the resize part. When I go beyond a certain length, the other div moves to the next line which I don't want to happen. Rather I want it to only stay in the same line.

I tried setting the position value to absolute and relative but still was not able to achieve what I want.

**This is my Code:**

```css
.res {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
.resright {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="col-md-2 res">
        <p>Hello how are u?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 resright">
        <p>ratatatatatata</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Please check this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/krXuSkGHotc2jBt2oMtO)

Comment: do you see any sample on web so we can see what is you want, i mean the output you want.

Comment: no I cannot find any.

Comment: @mmativ do u want me to explain it further ?

Comment: i see you dont want a breakpoints in your div?

Comment: because `col` in bootstrap are automatic move to other line when you got the max-width of the element.

Comment: is there a way I can stop that ?

Comment: Also I want this only when I view on a pc. But in other responsive versions, I want it to move to the next line. This is because in high res screen, my content appears so small. I want them to be able to resize it and also maintain view.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below css

```
.res, .resright{
  border: 2px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  resize: both;
}
```

Comment: This works partially. But it does not work on when I resize the other div